# am I do something wrong with my IDS snort.conf? Failed to detect Scan Nmap and DOS hping in other IP

Tags: snort

I've got some problem using Snort here. I have some [topologies](https://prntscr.com/njkx4l) that run under GNS3 for my research. I try to penetration testing to my topology that have IDS Snort in Windows 7 using [NMAP](https://prntscr.com/njkve8) (scan) and [hping3](https://prntscr.com/njkvdc) (TCP syn flood dos). When I try to scan and dos IP address of my IDS Server (192.168.10.4) it appears alert. But when I try to penetration testing to User 2 IP (192.168.10.2) it's doesn't appear alert.  Is there something wrong with my snort.conf in windows 7?

Click [here](https://pastebin.com/TaD1Sq20) "My Snort Config"

I try to change my ipvar HOME_NET, but still, no luck when I try to pentest

```
ipvar HOME_NET 192.168.10.0/24
```

change to

```
ipvar HOME_NET 192.168.10.1/24,192.168.10.2/24,192.168.10.3/24,192.168.10.4/24,192.168.10.5/24
```

I expect that when I try to penetration testing in other IP except for my IDS Server. it would give me some alert too...

Answer (score 0):

@Hanif
I believe the question to be posed is where do you want to install snort sensors and what are your desired results.
Some insight from the early 2000s. http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=21778&seqNum=9

To me it looks like you have installed the IDS on its own host and you anticipate it to cover the other three, well two host running windows. You want to "pentest" the windows machines and see what IDS alerts show for such attacks.

I would urge you to install snort on the two windows hosts and have all the alerts aggregate into something like Elasticsearch. Some further direction for you here: https://blog.snort.org/2017/11/snort-30-with-elasticsearch-logstash.html